# Load event not fired on Safari when reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onload-event, object-tag

I have a simple SVG loaded inside a `object` tag like the code below. On Safari, the `load` event is fired just once, when I load the first time the page after opening the browser. All the other times it doesn't. I'm using the `load` event to initialize some animations with GSAP, so I need to know when the SVG is fully loaded before being able to select the DOM nodes. A quick workaround that seems to work is by using `setTimeout` instead of attaching to the event, but it seems a bit akward as slower networks could not have load the `object` in the specified amount of time. I know this event is not really standardized, but I don't think I'm the first person that faced this problem. How would you solve it?

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('my-element').getElementsByTagName('object')[0];

myElement.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var svgDocument = this.contentDocument;
    var myNode = svgDocument.getElementById('my-node');

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer to a more specific question. It would be nice if the title specifically referenced problems loading an SVG DOM within an <object> tag, and the .contentDocument property returning null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds more like the problem is  that, when the data is cached, the load event fires **before** you attached the handler.

What you can try is to reset the data attribute once you attached the event :

```
object.addEventListener('load', onload_handler);
// reset the data attribte so the load event fires again if it was cached
object.data = object.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem while developing an Electron application. In my workflow I edit `index.html` and `renderer.js` in VSCode, and hit `<Ctrl>+R` to see the changes. I only restart the debugger to capture changes made to the `main.js` file.

I want to load an SVG that I can then manipulate from my application. Because the SVG is large I prefer to keep it in an external file that gets loaded from disk. To accomplish this, the HTML file `index.html` contains this declaration:

```
<object id="svgObj" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/file.svg"></object>
```

The application logic in `renderer.js` contains:

```
let svgDOM     // global to access SVG DOM from other functions
const svgObj = document.getElementById('svgObj')

svgObj.onload = function () {
    svgDOM = this.contentDocument
    mySvgReady(this)
}
```

The problem is non-obvious because it appears intermittent: When the debugger/application first starts this works fine. But when reloading the application via `<Ctrl>+R`, the `.contentDocument` property is `null`.

After much investigation and hair-pulling, a few long-form notes about this include:

- Using `svgObj.addEventListener ('load', function() {...})` instead of
  `svgObj.onload` makes no difference. Using `addEventListener`
  is *better* because attempting to set another handler via 'onload'
  will replace the current handler. Contrary to other `Node.js`
  applications, you do not need to `removeEventListener` when the element
  is removed from the DOM. Old versions of IE (pre-11) had problems but
  this should now be considered safe (and doesn't apply to Electron anyway).
- Usage of `this.contentDocument` is preferred. There is a nicer-looking
  `getSVGDocument()` method that works, but this appears to be for backwards
  compatibility with old Adobe tools, perhaps Flash. The DOM returned is the same.

The SVG DOM appears to be permanently cached once loaded as described by @Kaiido, except that I believe the event **never** fires. What's more, in `Node.js`, the SVG DOM remains cached in the same `svgDOM` variable it was loaded into. I don't understand this at all. My intuition suggests that the `require('renderer.js')` code in `index.html` has cached this in the module system somewhere, but changes to renderer.js do take effect so this can't be the whole answer.

Regardless, here is an alternate approach to capturing the SVG DOM in Electron's render process that is working for me:

```
let svgDOM     // global to access from other functions
const svgObj = document.getElementById('svgObj')

svgObj.onload = function () {
    if (svgDOM) return mySvgReady(this) // Done: it already loaded, somehow
    if (!this.contentDocument) {        // Event fired before DOM loaded
        const oldDataUri = svgObj.data  // Save the original "data" attribute
        svgObj.data = ''                // Force it to a different "data" value
        // setImmediate() is too quick and this handler can get called many
        // times as the data value bounces between '' and the actual SVG data.
        // 50ms was chosen and seemed to work, and no other values were tested.
        setTimeout (x => svgObj.data = oldDataUri, 50)
        return;
    }
    svgDOM = this.contentDocument
    mySvgReady(this)
}
```

Next, I was very disappointed to learn that the CSS rules loaded by `index.html` can't access the elements within the SVG DOM. There are a number of ways to inject the stylesheet into the SVG DOM programmatically, but I ended up changing my `index.html` to this format:

```
<svg id="svgObj" class="svgLoader" src="images/file.svg"></svg>
```

I then added this code to my DOM setup code in `renderer.js` to load the SVG directly into the document. If you are using a compressed SVG format I expect you will need to do the decompression yourself.

```
const fs = require ('fs')  // This is Electron/Node. Browsers need XHR, etc.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ...
    document.querySelectorAll ('svg.svgLoader').forEach (el => {
        const src = el.getAttribute ('src')
        if (!src) throw "SVGLoader Element missing src"
        const svgSrc = fs.readFileSync (src)
        el.innerHTML = svgSrc
    })
    ...
})
```

I don't necessarily love it, but this is the solution I'm going with because I can now change classes on the SVG object and my CSS rules apply to the elements within the SVG. For example, these rules from `index.css` can now be used to declaritively alter which parts of the SVG are displayed:

```
...
#svgObj.cssClassBad #groupBad,
#svgObj.cssClassGood #groupGood {
    visibility: visible;
}
...
```