# alternative to javascript load for an object of type image/svg-xml

Tags: javascript, image, object, svg, onload

my load function in chrome is giving me different values for the height and width of the image on the first load. it gives correct values only once i reload the same image.

is there an alternative to checking if an image has loaded?

i call it to check if the svg image is loaded.
1) i create an object in js of type image/svg-xml
2) onload { get the height and width } *ISSUE HERE*
3) do something with these 2 values

because the first load is wrong the 3) step also generates incorrect output (for the first load only) subsequent loads of the image are fetched from the cache and the correct values are given.

```
this.svg = null;
 this._W = 0;
 this._H = 0;


this.svg.addEventListener('load',function() {
    this._W = jQuery(".SVGImage").width();
    this._H = jQuery(".SVGImage").height();
    this._best();
}.bind(this));
```

in IE and firefox my function works perfectly fine on the 1st load and it gets the correct height and width. But in chrome the 1st load gives different values to the subsequent loads of the same image.

_best() function works fine for all other functions using it. so the problem isnt here but it looks something like:

```
var x = this._x - (this._imageW - this._canvas.clientWidth) / 2;
var y = this._y - (this._imageH - this._canvas.clientHeight) / 2;
......
```

the 1st load: image zoomed in (because values for _W and _H are incorrect.
2nd load + = all fine :)

Comment: Well svg is scalable (Scalable Vector Graphics), so does it matter what height width you get? As you could scale it to whatever dimensions you wanted/needed and it would still look the same as long as you kept the aspect ratio. Also the first load is more than likely not wrong, the dimensions are probably those set within the [viewbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

Comment: I will later use the height and width in another function to calculate how to center the image to fit it on the screen according to clientw/h and imagew/h @PatrickEvans this is why i want the values correctly on the 1st load

Comment: How do you get the width and height?

Comment: How are you checking "if an image has loaded" currently. Post the code so we can see if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I was looking for a possible cause and then stumbled upon [this oddity](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYmwPiKxcXDrwOi3Tu0G?p=preview) When set to `cm` values, then documentElement's rect is different than the `<object>`containing the document one. Am I correct in thinking that the documentElement's one is the one we should look at ?

Comment: @Sarah maybe related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/34677628/3702797

Comment: thankyou it works for local files. but i cant use content document for URL loaded images. it says ---> security error. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8089" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…) @Kaiido

Comment: @Sarah, I suspect more that your are in the [cache problem case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677628/load-event-not-fired-on-safari-when-reloading-page). The other comment was just because I'm unsure what's hapenning with these `cm` values, but is not directly related to your issue. I should make more research and then ask a question my-self about it.