# SVG onload event listener doesn't seem to fire in Edge

Tags: javascript, svg, microsoft-edge

I have an SVG image on my website that gets customized with information from the server when the page loads. I've included the image using an `<object>` tag. I then use javascript to change the text in the svg when it loads:

```
<body>

...

<object id="svg-img" data="~/Images/svg-img.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

...

<script>
    var svgImg = document.getElementById("svg-img");

    svgImg.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var svgDoc = svgImg.contentDocument;
        svgDoc.getElementById("element-to-change").textContent = "New content received by the server";
    }, false);
</script>
</body>
```

This works exactly as expected on all browsers except Microsoft Edge. When I debug using the Edge developer tools and set a breakpoint inside the event listener, it never hits the breakpoint; leading me to believe the event isn't firing. Is there something different I need to do to get this to work in Edge?

Comment: Perhaps Edge doesn't support ~ I'm actually surprised that anything does really.

Comment: What if you try to reset your object's data after you attached th event handler? (`svgImg.addEventListener( .... }); svgImg.data = svgImg.data;`). Safari [had a *bug*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677628/load-event-not-fired-on-safari-when-reloading-page/34678969#34678969) (which wasn't really one according to specs...) where they fired the event even before you had a chance to attach it. Maybe Edge does the same.

Comment: @Kaiido, you should post that as an answer, because that fixed it right up for me!