# How to tell if an inline object tag has loaded its data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using some pre declared `<object>` tag to load some SVG

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="some.svg"></object>
```

I want to manipulate that SVG after it's loaded. How do I wait for it to load and make sure I get the load event. In other words, do I need to handle a case where the object may have already loaded before I have a chance to attach an `load` event.

What was doing is calling `getSVGDocument` and if it returned null then adding the `load` event. That failed on Firefox and Safari.

My current solution is to try to reload the svg to force a load event

```
  class Waiter {
    constructor() {
      this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.resolve = resolve;
      });
    }
  }

  async function getSVGDocument(elem) {
    const data = elem.data;
    elem.data = '';
    elem.data = data;
    const waiter = new Waiter();
    elem.addEventListener('load', waiter.resolve);
    await waiter.promise;
    return elem.getSVGDocument();
  }
```

It seems to work but also seems like a horrible hack.

Is there some other way to tell if the `<object>` has loaded. Apparently `<img>` tag has a [`completed` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) but `<object>` doesn't appear to have anything similar unless I'm staring right at it.

Comment: You can avoid the double load by using an inline handler to set a data attribute and then checking the attribute to see if it's already loaded before adding your handler. e.g. `onload="setAttribute('data-loaded', 'true')"`. Also be aware that Chrome doesn't fire the `load` event if the object is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, setting the data again **after** you set up the load handler is the only cross-browser way of handling this.
Safari has the very bad habit of firing this event when the data is cached before below scripts had a chance to even get parsed <sub>([see this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677628/load-event-not-fired-on-safari-when-reloading-page/34678969#34678969))</sub>.

But since the browser should anyway use the cache (if your server is well configured), it's not such a big deal to set the data again. Now, if you really don't want, you can always set it as a data-attribute first, and when your script execute then only will you set the real `data` attribute:

```js
obj.onload = e => console.log('loaded');
obj.data = obj.dataset.source;
```

```html
<object data-source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg" id="obj"></object>
```

But beware, while it would seem HTMLObjectElement was intended to be the best element to load svg files, in turns out that because of weirdy, to say the least, implementations, you may prefer to use an iframe instead, which is a lot more reliable.
For instance, both Safari and Chrome will reload the object's content every time you to hide + show the element.
Here is just an example demonstrating how their implementation is buggy and can be dangerous, which is also why I give it only as [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lavkefbm/).

```js
obj.onload = e => console.log('loaded');
```

```css
object:hover{ display:none; }
```

```html
<object data="foo.svg" id="obj"></object>
```

In chrome, simply hovering this <object> will start an infinite loop of load/unload/load... triggering the event every time.

So yes, even if it requires a bit more of css, I can only advise to you to use an <iframe> instead.